# Область применения и происхождение слова "пацан"

Tags: этимология, лексика, стилистика, жаргон

Слово ***пацан*** имеет **пометку разг.,** но используется в речи часто. Это и речь персонажей в художественной литературе, и публицистика. Есть фильм с таким названием.

**Но вот происхождение** у  слова смутное, вроде бы есть две версии, одна другой хуже. Как-то после знакомства с ними  не хочется употреблять это слово. **И прилично ли вообще им пользоваться?**

**Также непонятно,  в какой среде это слово применяется,** я как-то от окружающих его не слышу. Может быть, оно характерно для определенных  областей?

**Из словаря:**

**ПАЦАН**,  м. Разг. Мальчишка. П. лет двенадцати. // Сын-мальчик. Поздравьте, у меня родился п.

**Примеры:**

**Пацан** на велике нарезал вокруг стола опасные круги, не обращая внимания на окрики взрослых. [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]

― В садике оба, **и пацан** и девчонка, где им еще-то быть, ― медсестра опять засмеялась. [Яна Жемойтелите. Аисты (2002)]

В современной школе сплошь и рядом бывают ситуации (учителя не дадут соврать), когда на уроке истории встаёт **пацан** и заявляет, что ... [Андрей Петров,  «Не расплескать патриотизм» // «Родина», 2008]

Answer (score 2):

Есть добротная статья лингвиста Добродомова.

Он утверждает следуюшее.

Слово пацан, имеющее в современном языке яркую окраску сниженности, и сейчас обычно в русских текстах, без особых целей не употребляющееся, в словарях и текстах XIX в. неизвестно и появляется только в 20-х гг. XX в., что относительно хорошо показано в недавней статье новосибирского языковеда М.Т. Дьячка: "Первым письменным свидетельством его существования является, видимо, отрывок из "Тихого Дона" М.А. Шолохова: "Пацан, неси сюда!" (среди реплик на привокзальной площади в Ростове; кто говорит, непонятно, возможно, один из упомянутых чуть выше матросов - черноморцев) (Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга 2, 1928 г.). Чуть позже слово пацанёнок в нейтральном значении использовано у Н. А. Островского в речи кочегара Андрея Птахи: "Василёк, братишка! Пацаненок... Васька, стервец!" (Островский. Рожденные бурей, 1936 г.).

Эти два примера по-своему показательны. Во-первых, они явно указывают на южное (причерноморско-южноукраинское) происхождение слова. Во-вторых, и в том, и в другом случае слово пацан использовано для характеристики представителей люмпенизированной среды".

Но относительно слабое распространение этого слова в текстах (особенно ранних) советского времени автор ошибочно объясняет идеологическими причинами, как бы забывая о верно им установленном происхождении слова пацан из "люмпенизированной среды", которая высоким престижем в обществе не пользовалась, как и слова, вышедшие из этой среды: "В сталинскую эпоху с ее жестким контролем над литературой и литературным языком слово пацан не часто появляется в произведениях печатной словесности. Ср., однако, следующие примеры: Я, пацаном когда был, в Америку совсем уже бежать собрался, золото в Клондайке искать. Стащил двустволку у отца, сухарей набрал. Даже на норвежскую шхуну забрался. Мы во Владивостоке тогда жили (Некрасов В. В окопах Сталинграда, 1946); - Не ходи с ними, пацан, - ввязался вдруг Борька. - Давай, лучше врасшибалочку постукаем (Рыбаков А. Кортик, 1948)".

Следовало бы обратить внимание на то, что в этих примерах слово пацан употреблено в прямой речи персонажей как их речевая 
характеристика. Нужно, однако, отметить еще одно явление, характерное для юношеского жаргона: очень часто слова получают в нем значение, отличное от того, какое они имели в языке, откуда они были заимствованы. Так, например, известно, что в нашем крае **фабзавучники сплошь называют друг друга "пацанами"**. Слово это получило всеобщее признание и по смыслу равносильно слову: подросток, мальчик, молокосос.

Очень часто ученики старших групп фабзавуча называют "пацанами" младших своих сотоварищей и обижаются, если к ним прилагают это название. Между тем, "пацан" - **слово украинское и означает: подсвинок, молодой кабан"**.

В главе "Фабзавучники и язык" также помещен краткий тематический словарик юношеского жаргона, где фигурируют слова пацан и пацанка с синонимами: "Подросток, мальчишка - пацан (украинское подсвинок), шкет. Девушка - пацáнка, симáха (девушка, за которой ухаживают). Это его подруга - это его симáха".

"В конце 1920-х гг. слово получает и свою первую словарную фиксацию. А.В. Миртов включает его в словарь "Из лексикона ростовских беспризорников и босяков" (1929), определяя значение слова очень лаконично: пацан - "мальчуган".

В то же время А.В. Миртовым отмечено и проникновение слова за пределы среды деклассированных элементов **в народные говоры**: "Пацáн - уличный мальчик. Новое городское слово <со ссылкой на запись в Ростове и Новочеркасске - И.Д. >, проникающее уже в станицу. Вариант **бацан"** .
Но процесс распространения слова не был, однако, стремительным: "Очень интересны свидетельства современников той эпохи. Так, по словам писателя и филолога Г.П. Помазкова (род. 1922), уроженца станицы Тацинской Ростовской обл., слово пацан не использовалось в речи жителей казачьих станиц в 30-е гг., но его можно было услышать в Ростове, Таганроге и других крупных городах юга России. При этом слово пацан обозначало мальчишку 12-13 лет - **сорванца и хулигана**" .

В кратком трехтомном "Словаре русских донских говоров" (Ростов-на-Дону, 1975-1976) ни пацан, ни бацан не зафиксированы, но это произошло не потому, что слово в этих говорах отсутствует, а потому что составители не включили его в словарь из-за наличия его в академической лексикографии, куда слово неожиданно попало в середине 50-х гг. XX в.

Одновременно в 20-е гг. XX столетия слово пацан обнаружило экспансию и на Север России, как это было отмечено А.М. Селищевым в книге "Язык революционной эпохи" (М., 1928. С. 75-79), на фоне общего явления: "За последние годы получили широкое распространение слова из "жаргона преступников". Эти слова переняты были сперва лицами низших, а затем средних слоев городского населения и лицами фабрично-заводской среды" http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/dobrodomov-09.htm

Такой версии придерживаются многие лингвисты и филологи-любители, они сходятся во времени проникновения слова - 20-е годы 20 века - и южном происхождении. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка говорит нам: «Корень в этом слове, вероятно, междометно-звукоподражательного характера. Cр. укр. «паць» и «паць-паць» — межд., возглас, которым подзывают свиней». У Фасмера тоже что-то похожее.

**Возможно, это слово вначале означало «свинопас», «пастух», «пастушок», «мальчик на побегушках» или просто «малый».**

Но со временем слово стало приобретать и другие значения. Селищев в 1928 г. вносит это слово в «Cлова воровского жаргона», а Миртов в 1929 г. даёт «пацан» — «мальчуган» как слово ростовских беспризорников и босяков. То же нам говорит и толк. словарь Ожегова: пацан — (прост.) мальчишка. В действительности, сегодня значение этого слова шире.
Это человек в возрасте от 5 до 20 лет. Используется оно и в адрес людей старше этого возраста, вплоть до 35 лет, но уже реже, когда говорят о хорошем знакомом, друге, на дворовом жаргоне — это «свой парень в компании».

А вот словарь-справочник «Современный русский жаргон уголовного мира» указывает нам на другие значения этого слова: 1) мальчишка, 2) воспитанник, пользующийся определенными привилегиями и 3) молодой вор, совершающий кражи под руководством опытного вора.
Этого молодого вора ещё называют «пацаном зелёным», а в том случае, если он совершает успехи, то его называют «пацаном золотым».
Кстати, сейчас это слово уже не относится к одним только представителям мужского пола, но приобрело и женский род.
Словарь-справочник даёт слово «пацанка» 1) девчонка, 2) молодая воровка. В первом значении это — «своя», дворовая, девчонка из компании, подросток до 18—19 лет. Во втором значении — это, возможно, тот же путь от воспитанницы до «зелёной» и «золотой» пацанки.

Достаточно  правдоподобный вариант, соответствующий общепринятому пониманию слова, - от "Paisano" (исп.) - соотечественник, земляк, деревенщина, "paesano"- земляк, крестьянин, сельский житель. Правдоподобный, потому что на Украине (особенно в Одессе) в то время было много выходцев из Италии - молодёжные банды, взаимодействующие с беспризорниками.

Вариант с оскорбляющим  значением считаю надуманным. Происхождение от еврейского "поц" признают если только в криминальной среде, они там всё к этому значению сводят, один сказал - другие подхватили.

Мне это слово не кажется даже просторечным, разговорное - да, я выросла в маленьком городке в заводском районе, наши ребята его использовали именно в значении "свой парень", "мальчишка" без всяких неприличностей.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно.   Мне слово не нравится, но я не нахожу ему синонима, когда оно используется в качестве обращения: Слушай,  пацан...". Ну не мальчик же или мальчишка.

Comment: Ну да, в подростковой среде оно в самый раз, а нам с Вами вряд ли пригодится, мы скажем: "Послушайте, молодой человек..."

Comment: Людмила, непонятно, где кончаются слова Добродомова и начинается Ваш комментарий. Для выделения чужого текста Вы можете воспользоваться опцией "цитата" из верхнего меню.

Comment: Дело в том, что текст цитаты  будет очень уж большой, а внутри цитаты ещё чьи-то слова, будет цитата в цитате. К тому же кое-что я пропускала, некорректно будет. По-моему, и так понятно, что ДО ссылки - статья Добродомова.

Answer (score 1):

"Пацан" — это жаргонизм, плотно вошедший в повседневный обиход русскоязычного населения в начале 20-го века (ранее не встречался ни в словарях, ни в литературе). Синонимы: парнишка, юноша, отрок, босяк.
О происхождении... Позволю себе предположить, что слово это своими корнями уходит на восток, ибо оконцовка "цан" русскому языку не свойственна, а там встречается (дацан — монастырь, цан — иней, мороз). Первый слог "па" указывает на принадлежность к мужскому началу и встречается во многих языках нашего континента: папа, парень, парубок, падре, паша́.
Есть ещё один жаргонизм, плотно вошедший в обиход на просторах СНГ, который помог моему сознанию почуять восточный след, — "пахан". Здесь слились два слова: папа и хан. Хан — титул восточного правителя. Папа — глава семейства. Слово обозначает авторитетного в преступном мире человека, но так же "паханом" между собой называют своих отцов некоторые отроки — пацаны.

Comment: Спасибо. А вы можете указать источники, которыми пользовались при ответе?

Comment: Да - моя голова.  Но я пытался в интернете найти какие-то тюркоязычные слова, схожие по звучанию и смыслу, - не получилось. Нужно идти в библиотеку за бумажными словарями.

Comment: У Вас хорошее чувство юмора.

Comment: Самое важное, Sharon, здесь то, что это слово по звучанию никак не может происходить из славянских пасюков, пастухов, свинопасов и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо,  это приятно!

Answer (score 0):

Интересное наблюдение про ПА и испанский след на Украине.
В целом всё указывает на хрен из идиша, ставшей основой воровского жаргона. Да и Украина многим, ох многим обязана и "обязана" евреям. Как ни крути, это свой, молодой, глупый, у которого энергия прёт между ног, а голова пока не работает.

Тема послереволюционная, так что к дате жёстко привязана, что сокращает список источников заимствования. И пац, легко может быть как эвфемизмом от поц (это же мат), так и просто созвучие. Я больше соглашусь, что пац на украине произошёл от поц, т.к. значение суть одно - молодой-активный.

Comment: На какой ещё хрен?